# How to send instance-wide notifications in PostgreSQL, across different databases?

Tags: postgresql, notifications

I'm using PostgreSQL's `NOTIFY` command to send async events to inform external programs of the changes happening inside a database. It works perfect but now I've got a new scenario. I need to have several databases within an instance of PostgreSQL.

As I've read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) and tested it myself, `NOTIFY` does not go beyond the borders of a database (to other databases within the PostgreSQL instance).

> Whenever the command NOTIFY channel is invoked, either by this session
>   or another one connected to the same database, all the sessions
>   currently listening on that notification channel are notified, and
>   each will in turn notify its connected client application.

Which means I have to listen to notifications of each database separately. And since I'm planning to provide my users with the capability to instantiate their own database on-demand, it means I have to make new listener connections for each new database as well. It poses a challenge and I really prefer if I can have a constant number of listener connections, regardless of the number of databases.

Does anyone know how to send notifications across databases in PostrgeSQL or some other feature I can use?

Comment: I haven't used `NOTIFY` yet, but this sounds like you should think about using a dedicated message queue instead of PostgreSQL. There might even be plugins that let you push directly into an AMQP queue (for example) from PostgreSQL, if you really need to broadcast from the database.

Comment: I am using RabbitMQ and a plugin which sends notifications from PosqtgreSQL to RabbitMQ but the problem is that the connection from RabbitMQ to PostgreSQL is capable of receiving notifications only within the database specified by the connection and not the other databases. In other words broadcasting in PostgreSQL using `NOTIFY` isn't that *broad*!

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I don't know the answer then.. Besides broadcasting from outside the database, which would probably scale better anyway, but needs code changes and causes more complexity... If you really need this feature, and no one comes of with an alterative solution, there might be the possibility of writing your own little PostgreSQL plugin that does exactly that. As a last resort of course.

Comment: Use schemas instead of databases and your problem disappears

Comment: @DanielVérité That's pretty smart but unfortunately I need the security of databases. Thanks anyways.